# ошибка при компиляции скетча ardupilot

Tags: c++, arduino

Балуюсь с "ардуиной", а точнее с `ardupilot 1.0.3` и пилотным контроллером на базе `arduino` "mega 2560".
Поставил все как было прописано в [вики](http://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/building-ardupilot-with-arduino-windows.html#building-ardupilot-with-arduino-windows)

Скопипастил скетч (нашел на просторах - была необходимость только получать данные с гироскопа).

Код скетча:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <AP_Common.h>
#include <AP_Progmem.h>
#include <AP_HAL.h>
#include <AP_HAL_AVR.h>
#include <AP_HAL_AVR_SITL.h>
#include <AP_HAL_Empty.h>
#include <AP_Math.h>
#include <AP_Param.h>
#include <AP_ADC.h>
#include <AP_InertialSensor.h>

const AP_HAL::HAL& hal = AP_HAL_BOARD_DRIVER;
AP_InertialSensor_MPU6000 ins;

void setup()
{
    ins.init(AP_InertialSensor::COLD_START,
             AP_InertialSensor::RATE_100HZ,
             NULL);

    // initialise sensor fusion on MPU6050 chip (aka     DigitalMotionProcessing/DMP)
    hal.scheduler->suspend_timer_procs();  // stop bus collisions
    ins.dmp_init();
    hal.scheduler->resume_timer_procs();
}

void loop()
{
// Ask MPU6050 for orientation
    ins.update();
    float roll = 0, pitch = 0, yaw = 0;
    ins.quaternion.to_euler(&roll, &pitch, &yaw);
    roll = ToDeg(roll);
    pitch = ToDeg(pitch);
    yaw = ToDeg(yaw);

    hal.console->printf("Gyro data. Pitch: %.3f, roll: %.3f, yaw: %.3f\n",       pitch, roll, yaw);
    hal.scheduler->delay(500);
    }

    AP_HAL_MAIN();
```

Однако, что то не срослось, при компиляции выкинуло следующее:

> In file included from sketch_aug19a.ino:2:0:
>   C:\GIT_PROJ\ardupilot\libraries\AP_Common/AP_Common.h:24:34: fatal
>   error: AP_HAL/AP_HAL_Boards.h: No such file or directory  #include
>   
>                                     ^ compilation terminated.

В чем может быть ошибка? 
В директории `AP_HAL` вполне себе лежит `AP_HAL_BOARDS.h`.

Comment: В любой непонятной ситуации ( связанной с ардуино) первый совет попробуйте переустановить иде )

Comment: если вы не читали то, что в ссылке по слову "вики", то расскажу краткую суть - там все начинается с установки ide ardupilot. То есть, малость кастомизированная ide специально под подобные полетные контроллеры... Так, что, ide была поставлена с нуля. Стандартная ide ардуины вообще не стала компилить, тож заругавшись на путь, а потом выдав, что этот скетч вообще не подходит для MEGA 2560

Answer (score 2):

Вы выбрали HAL Board? У меня была та же ошибка, пока я не выбрал корректную

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого ошибка должна пропасть

---

Также не забудьте установить все компоненты библиотек из папки ArduPilot/ArduCopter, которая предоставляется с Arduino IDE для ArduPilot.

Для этого переместите код из

[image: ArduPilot source libraries directory]

В

[image: ArduPilot Arduino IDE libraries directory]

Таким образом директория библиотек должна подхватиться ArduPilot Arduino IDE

[image: Updated contents of ArduPilot Arduino IDE libraries directory]

После этого проект должен собраться, правда с ошибками.

Из блога, [Compiling ArduCopter/ArduPilot with the Arduino IDE](https://wordpress.com/post/gr33nonline.wordpress.com/5427).

Comment: Да, HAL_board выбирал, библиотеки подключал